# Relating data on bounded contexts

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, persistence

One of the features of bounded contexts from DDD, as far as I understand, is that they are boundaries inside which the ubiquitous language suffers no ambiguities. In that case, if on a system we have the idea of Product, what a Product means might differ if we are talking about buying the product from the reseller or really selling the product to someone. In truth, the business logic might even change: when selling there might be some logic about discounts which doesn't make sense when buying the product. In that case we isolate the ubiquitous language creating two bounded contexts. Inside of which, there is the concept of product, but they mean different things.

The point is that there is usually many duplicate data. For instance, on the product example the name of the product, the category, the description are examples of things which would be the same. My doubt here is not on relating those duplicate informations on code, but rather when persisting the data.

How can we deal with this duplicate data when persisting it to a data store? Is there one recommended way to relate it or we simply keep it separate regardless of the redundancy it would bring?

Answer (score 4):

Bounded contexts shouldn't share the same data store.  If you have multiple bounded contexts, each with a `Product` entity, then each of these bounded contexts would most likely have a table/collection for storing `Products`.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian, for the answer. I've read sometimes that bounded contexts really shouldn't share the same data store. But having duplicate data around isn't a problem? Also, it is then necessary to ensure everything is in sync. How those things can be addressed?

Comment: Since I started designing my applications in an application-centric manner and not from the database upwards, I find that my entities, view models, web service messages, etc. become very individual, tailored and I don't get that duplication up through the layers that I used to.  Even bounded contexts, once everything is free to evolve on its own, my similar sounding entities stop looking so similar in their structure.  There's some interesting discussion in Eric Evans book about how systems/BCs relate to each other, upstream, downstream, etc.

Comment: It can mean more putting more thought into the communication between bounded contexts and keeping things in sync, but the advantages of having entities specifically for that BC that aren't contaminated with terms from other BCs is priceless.  I can't count how many systems I've worked on where yet another nullable column is just tagged onto the `Product` table.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips Big tables with holes are, luckily, not the only way of sharing data between bounded contexts. I'm not sure how that counts as a valid argument against shared data store.

Comment: @guillaume31 I'm guess my main point is, having 2 full-stack systems that both have the concept of `Products` (albeit with different properties), and a bit of code duplication, and they communicate across their BC (via web service, MQ, ESB, etc.), is infinitely better than having a shared database, with a single `Product` table, attempting to serve both BCs (systems).

Comment: Please define "better". I think it improves modularity, deployability and overall maintainability but requires extra synchronization work and is a huge, costly architectural shift if the OP's original target was vanilla non-CQRS, non-microservices DDD.

Comment: @guillaume31 true, there's always trade-offs.  I'd define "better" as all those things you list, particularly maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

You can use RPC as a way to integrate bounded contexts but this should really be limited in use. However, sometimes you need current data (price) and so this is an acceptable practice.